# Can not yum install anything

Tags: centos, yum

I'm on a new VPS running CentOS release 5.4 (Final) and using the DirectAdmin control panel.

When I try to run YUM for anything, I get the following error:

```
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
e2fsprogs-libs is needed by (installed) e2fsprogs-devel-1.39-20.el5.x86_64
Complete!
(1, [u'Please report this error in http://yum.baseurl.org/report'])
```

Which, that page doesn't work either!

I then proceeded to download e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7.tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs/files/e2fsprogs/v1.42.7/ and tried to install it...

'make' returns:

> make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7/lib/blkid'
>
> making all in lib/quota
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/root/e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7/lib/quota'
>
> make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../../lib/ext2fs/ext2_fs.h', needed by` mkquota.o'. Stop.
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7/lib/quota'
>
> make[1]: *** [all-libs-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7'
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

'make install' then outputs:

> making all in lib/quota
>
> make[1]: Entering directory `/root/e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7/lib/quota'
>
> make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../../lib/ext2fs/ext2_fs.h', needed by` mkquota.o'.  Stop.
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.7/lib/quota'
>
> make: *** [all-libs-recursive] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `yum distro-sync` to bring the system in sync with the package repository.

It appears that whoever built this VPS template got something out of sync (and for the love of Gawd, it's "5.4"?!) and distro-sync will bring you current.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that there either 2 packages of e2fsprogs-libs installed on the system and rpm db is complaining to yum or e2fsprogs-libs is installed but obsolete and conflicting with something which is not good.

My suggestion would be as a workaround you could try running "yum remove e2fsprogs-libs" and then "yum install e2fsprogs-libs"
Hope it will help you.

Comment: that was a no go... seeing as it was a new VPS and I was still in the process of migrating everything over, I just reformatted and tried again. seems to be working fine this time

Comment: Oh okay. Glad you were able to solve the issue other way